# Is my understanding of the A20 line check code correct?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader

I was following [this tutorial](https://wiki.osdev.org/A20_Line) on how to check and enable the A20 line. I think I understand it but can someone clarify it for me please?

The comments that were already in that tutorial start `; <comment>`,
My comments start `;<comment>`

```
; The following code is public domain licensed

[bits 16]

; Function: check_a20
;
; Purpose: to check the status of the a20 line in a completely self-contained state-preserving way.
;          The function can be modified as necessary by removing push's at the beginning and their
;          respective pop's at the end if complete self-containment is not required.
;
; Returns: 0 in ax if the a20 line is disabled (memory wraps around)
;          1 in ax if the a20 line is enabled (memory does not wrap around)

check_a20:
    pushf                                  ;Backup the current flags onto the stack
                                           ;Backup the below registers onto the stack
    push ds                                ;|
    push es                                ;|
    push di                                ;|
    push si                                ;-----

    cli                                    ;Disable interupts

    xor ax, ax                             ; ax = 0
    mov es, ax                             ;es = ax

    not ax                                 ; ax = 0xFFFF
    mov ds, ax                             ; ds = ax

    mov di, 0x0500                         ;Boot signature part one (0x55)
    mov si, 0x0510                         ;Boot signature part two (0xAA)

    mov al, byte [es:di]                   ;al = value at AA:55
    push ax                                ;Backup ax register onto the stack

    mov al, byte [ds:si]                   ;al = value at 55:AA
    push ax                                ;Backup al onto the stack

    mov byte [es:di], 0x00                 ;Memory location AA:55 = 0
    mov byte [ds:si], 0xFF                 ;Memory location at 55:AA = 0xFF

    cmp byte [es:di], 0xFF                 ;Does value at AA:55 = 0xFF? If so, this means A20 is disabled

    pop ax                                 ;Restore saved ax register
    mov byte [ds:si], al                   ;Set 55:AA to al

    pop ax                                 ;Restore ax register
    mov byte [es:di], al                   ;set AA:55 to al

    mov ax, 0                              ;Return status of this function = 0 (Disabled)
    je check_a20__exit                     ;A20 is disabled. Go to check_a20__exit

    mov ax, 1                              ;Return status of this function = 1 (Enabled)

check_a20__exit:
                                           ;Backup registers
    pop si
    pop di
    pop es
    pop ds
    popf                                   ;Backup flags

    ret                                    ;Return
```

If I do not understand some sections, could you please explain why?

Comment: `mov di, 0x0500` has no connection to the boot-sector signature the BIOS looks for to see if a drive contains a bootable boot-sector.  It's not `0x55`, it's `0x0500`, and `si` and `di` are being used as addresses, not data.

Comment: @PeterCordes I must be getting a bit confused then. From the link, it says `This can be achieved by comparing, at boot time in real mode, the bootsector identifier (0xAA55) located at address 0000:7DFE with the value 1 MiB higher which is at address FFFF:7E0E.` What does the boot signature got to do with it then? Also I now notice I got the bytes the wrong way. Part one is AA, part two is 55.

Comment: Also you should probably read this so you know why this code would even be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A20_line

Answer (score 5):

The code is checking whether `FFFF:0510` and `0000:0500` refer to the same address by writing to both and seeing if writing to one address overwrites the other.

As it turns out, `FFFF:0510` can represent the linear address `0x100500` rather than `0x500`, but only if A20 is enabled. So the code writes all zeros to the byte at `es:di` (aka `0000:0500`), and all ones to the byte at `ds:si` (aka `FFFF:0510`). If A20 is enabled, then the two segment:offset pairs refer to different addresses, the first write will stick, and `[es:di]` will contain zero. Otherwise, the two pairs refer to the same address, the second write will clobber the first, and `[es:di]` will contain `0xff`.

(By the way, `0x55` and `0xAA` aren't part of this; i'm not sure where you got those numbers from. The boot signature is typically at 0x7dfe, IIRC.)

Comment: So from what I can see (I may be wrong on this), is it checking for some sort of memory overflow then as you will be writing to two places? Or is this due to segments and offsets?

Comment: It's due to how the CPU calculates addresses in real mode. The reason for the A20 gate in the first place is that with more bits on the address bus, the addresses don't wrap around quite the way they did on the 8086. The A20 gate forces that wraparound in case some old software relied on it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed this line in the wiki:

> The following code performs a check (not like described above -- more directly).

If A20 is disabled, those two locations alias each other.  If not, they don't.  That's why it does two stores of different values, and then checks to see what's there.  (Whether the 2nd store aliased or not.)

If you were checking for the 0xAA55 signature at the high address, you'd be doing loads only.  Plus, the addresses (`FFFF:0500` and `0000:0510`), aren't equal to `0000:7DFE` (location of the boot sector signature) and `FFFF:7E0E` (possibly aliasing), even after normalizing.

You made up the AA and 55 out of thin air; they don't appear anywhere in the code, and there's no load from the address where you'd find them.